# Retrieve product id inside

Tags: javascript, php

How do I retrieve the `product_id` inside `modal_product_extension()`?

It returns `modal_product_extension('', 'Shoes')`
Thanks in advance!! :)

Here's my code:

```
function show_products() {
        GLOBAL $db_conn;
        $search_query="SELECT p.*, pe.* FROM tblproduct p JOIN (SELECT p.product_id, MIN(pe.product_extension_id) AS product_extension_id FROM tblproduct p LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension pe ON pe.product_id = p.product_id GROUP BY product_id) product_unique LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension pe ON pe.product_extension_id = product_unique.product_extension_id WHERE p.product_id = product_unique.product_id"; 
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $search_query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $status = ($row['product_stocks'] == 0) ? '<label class="label label-danger">Out of stocks</label>' : '<label class="label label-success">In stocks</label>';
            ?>  
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$row['product_name']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['product_brand']?></td>
                    <td>category</td>
                    <td>&#8369;<?=number_format($row['product_price'], 2)?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['product_size']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['product_stocks']?></td>
                    <td><?=$status?></td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a onclick="modal_product_extension('<?=$row['product_id']?>', '<?=$row['category_name']?>')">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a onclick="modal_add_image('<?=$row['product_id']?>', '<?=$row['product_brand']?>')">
                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-lg"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><a onclick="edit_product_by_id('<?=$row['product_id']?>')"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a></td>
                    <td align="center"><a onclick="delete_product_by_id('<?=$row['product_id']?>')"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are having multiple `product_id` in your response can u please check for the same by triggering query into the database.

Comment: Why do you need retreive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an alias for your `product_id` field and refer to the alias in your PHP code, because the field name is not unique (it is in  both joined tables):

So your function became:

```
function show_products() {
        GLOBAL $db_conn;
        $search_query="SELECT p.product_id as P_ID, p.*, pe.* FROM tblproduct p JOIN (SELECT p.product_id, MIN(pe.product_extension_id) AS product_extension_id FROM tblproduct p LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension pe ON pe.product_id = p.product_id GROUP BY product_id) product_unique LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension pe ON pe.product_extension_id = product_unique.product_extension_id WHERE p.product_id = product_unique.product_id"; 
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $search_query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $status = ($row['product_stocks'] == 0) ? '<label class="label label-danger">Out of stocks</label>' : '<label class="label label-success">In stocks</label>';
            ?>  
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$row['product_name']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['product_brand']?></td>
                    <td>category</td>
                    <td>&#8369;<?=number_format($row['product_price'], 2)?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['product_size']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['product_stocks']?></td>
                    <td><?=$status?></td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a onclick="modal_product_extension('<?=$row['P_ID']?>', '<?=$row['category_name']?>')">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a onclick="modal_add_image('<?=$row['product_id']?>', '<?=$row['product_brand']?>')">
                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-lg"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><a onclick="edit_product_by_id('<?=$row['product_id']?>')"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a></td>
                    <td align="center"><a onclick="delete_product_by_id('<?=$row['product_id']?>')"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks brother! :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the sql statement and run it to make sure you're not returning more than one product_id, which is why the associative array is not working as expected.

The solution is to give it an alias that is not used in the same query